# jquery datepicker UI on select event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker to setup a calendar of events. I've created a string to give a class "dayWithEvents" to some dates in the calendar and what I want to do is when you click on one of these dates something to happen and something else when you click on days without this classs.
So I give a specific class to some dates like this:

```
var eventsString = [
        '11/17/2014',
        '11/18/2014',
        '11/2/2014'
    ];
function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < eventsString.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(eventsString[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'dayWithEvents'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

And then I try to trigger the event when you click on one of those dates:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('dayWithEvents')){
            alert('day with event');
        }
    });
```

The problem is that this work only the first time I click on one of the days that have this class. If I click it a second time, it won't work and also if I fist click another date and then one of the dates with this class it won't work.

You can see this calendar here: http://bootstrap.expert/tmp/cal/

Any ideea how to make it work everytime I click on these dates?
Thanks

Comment: you have to use the `.on()` delegate function: (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: which calendar plugin are you using?

Comment: @Avishek he uses the jquery ui datepicker

Comment: the html code is irrelevant. it's as simple as <div id="calendar"></div> because I am using jquery UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the event handler each time the calender DOM reloads.
If there is any callback event available for the calendar, declare the click event inside the callback.

Or, you can re-initiate the event on each click.

```
function eventInit(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('dayWithEvents')){
            alert('day with event');
            eventInit();
        }
    });
}
eventInit();
```

Comment: @VDesign to call it recursively

Comment: The if statement you can remove and do `.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td.dayWithEvents`

Comment: @VDesign yes that can be done.. the OP can do however he wants to. but that was not the actual problem. that is optimization

Comment: I know, it was for optimization

Answer (score 0):

Change you js code into this:

Use the `.on()` event handler to dynamically add the click event to all your table cells that has the class `dayWithEvents`

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').on('click', 'tbody tr td.dayWithEvents', function(){
    alert('day with event');
});
```